# SQL Query with ORDER BY

Tags: sql

I have a table in my SQL database that looks like:

```
id    type      radius
-------------------------
1     type1     0.25
2     type2     0.59
3     type1     0.26
4     type1     0.78
5     type3     0.12
6     type2     0.45
7     type3     0.22
8     type3     0.98
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to define a `SELECT` query which returns the lowest radius for each type.

In other words, the results I am looking for would be:

Results:

```
id    type      radius
-------------------------
1     type1     0.25
6     type2     0.45
7     type3     0.22
```

I assume I use `ORDER BY` to order the radius from lowest to highest and grab the lowest. However, I also assume I need to use `DISTINCT` on the type, but I can't figure out how to pull this off.

Any expert SQL'ers out there have any idea of this type of `SELECT` query is possible? Any help is much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to group by type, and then get the minimal radius from that type, and sort it by type

```
SELECT type, MIN(radius) FROM table
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type
```

If you want the id to go with the min, you cannot do it as I first typed: that id is a semi-random Id for type. Sadly, you'll have to settle for (from the top of my head)

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.type,t1.radius FROM table t1 
WHERE radius = ( 
     SELECT MIN(radius) FROM table
     WHERE radius = t1.radius
   )
```

**(final edit: you've got to test that last one, basic warning is that in the first query you cannot reliably fetch the Id, because it will NOT belong specifically to the type that has the lowest radius)**

Comment: Great! This makes perfect sense. Could you explain the use of SORT BY in this case? Do you think that would be necessary to include?

Comment: sort by will put the types in order so if you had the types all mixed up in you database you'd get them in order in the result

Comment: Nah, not really usefull at all, its just to make sure you get the "type1" first etc. You could sort by id, to get the one with the lowest Id first. Just a headsup: will you use the id? because the id is useless in this case. (i'll edit my answer for that)

Comment: wouldn't that have to be `ORDER BY` (instead of SORT BY) ??

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
SELECT min(radius) FROM table GROUP BY type
```

min will return the minimum value as distinct will return distinct values but group by allows you to perform the query on distinct fields.

check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
(and also http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp)

Comment: It seems like you should should know about aggregation.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine min and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.type,t1.radius FROM table GROUP BY type ORDER BY radius
```

Since order by defaults to ascending the minimum value should be the one shown.